# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReviewsController#create / Couldn't find Review without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am struggling with posting a review to a profile page linked to a user. I have a bit complicated routung, I know, it was not the best idea to go this way, but for now these routes are in every view I have, so changing them would be a horror to me, as I am a beginner and creating what I have for now already took me two weeks. Here are the routes.

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :user, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: "users/registrations" }
    resources :users do
        resources :profiles do
            resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
        end
    end
    root 'home#index'
end
```

Ok, for the reviews I have a form, which reflects this complicated routing and works in terms of being showed on the page:

```
<div class="submit-review">
  <%= form_for([@user, @profile, @review], :url => user_profile_reviews_path(@user, @profile)) do |f| %>
    <label for="review">How was your experience?</label><br>
    <%= f.label :rating %>
    <%= f.select :rating, options_for_select([["Please select one", ""], 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) %>

    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder:"Please enter your feedback here" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit your review", class: "btn btn-default" %> <br><br>
  <% end %>
```

But, clicking the "Submit" button I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReviewsController#create
Couldn't find Review without an ID
Extracted source (around line #35):

  def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Here is my Reviews Controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile
  before_action :set_review, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

def create
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    @review = @profile.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save
        redirect_to @profile
    else
        redirect_to @profile, notice: "Error saving"
    end
end

  private

  def review_params
    params.permit(:content, :rating)
  end

def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  end

  def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

And just in case, here is my Profiles Controller

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      def index
        @profiles = Profile.all
      end

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
        @reviews = Review.where("profile_id = ?", params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      end

      def edit
        @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
      end

      def create
        @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
        respond_to do |format|
          if @profile.save
            format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id, current_user.profile.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @profile.update(profile_params)
            format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user.id, current_user.profile.id), notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @profile.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to profiles_url, notice: 'Profile was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        def set_profile
          @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
        end

        def profile_params
          params.permit(:about, :rating, :avatar)
        end
end
```

I didn't find an answer to this by now, so please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In set_review you do

```
 @review = Review.find(params[:id])
```

What this does is look into the url of the current page to get the id of the record in question(In this case Review).  Because it is a create action no ID exists for the record(it hasn't been created yet) in the DB or in the URL.  When your call to set_review looks into the URL for the id it raises this error.

if you change

```
before_action :set_review, only: [:new, :create]
```

to be

```
before_action :set_review, only: :new
```

It should get you past this error.  Also for future reference the output of running `rake routes` is usually more helpful than posting the routes file for debugging.  Also when you are beginning never be afraid to start fresh once you have learned some lessons.